# Is there any way to configure angular.json to stop attaching chunks to index.html?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to make a Angular 7 Boilerplate to export web elements to develop like Micro Frontends style.

I already have an project in Angular 5 to use as **Base project** and my idea is to create **Modules project** end export to reference from **Base project** as module
like `<script type="module" src="//localhost:8085/w-comp/main.js"></script>`

In **Modules project**. I want to use built **Base project** as contentBase like this example I made with vanilla here: https://github.com/walker-walks/angular-with-external-web-components/tree/master/external

For this, I want to stop Angular attaching chunks to `index.html` automatically. Is there any way?

[image: chunks the Angular import automatically]